# Using a String on a WSH Shell Popup

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Msg()
    Dim Shell
    Dim t As String
    t = "My Msg Test"
    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Shell.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup(""&t"",3,""Title""))"
End Sub
```

The above code displays a msgbox with the Title: `Title` and Msg: `&t`

I am looking for a msgbox with the Title: `Title` and Msg: `My Msg Test`

Is there a way to display a message using an string (in this case string `t`)

Comment: Not enough quotes: `"mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup(""" & t & """,3,""Title""))"`

Comment: Just VBA line `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(t, 3,"Title")`

Comment: Thanks Rory! it did work!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the in-built `MsgBox` function? i.e.:

```
Sub msg()
    Dim t As String
    t = "My Msg Test"
    MsgBox t, vbYesNoCancel, "Title"
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not using msgbox because I want that msg to disappear after 3 seconds automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set x = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
x.popup etc
```

Any COM language can call ANY COM library. That is what COM is about.

VBScript has a small number of Functions that VBA don't have but VBScript is PASTABLE into VBA. That was a design goal.